# "North-country" refers to where?

Tags: meaning, literature

"North-country" refers to where?

The author has come to the conclusion, as already stated, that up to a point they are under the control of the medium, and that beyond that point they are not. He cannot easily forget the distress and embarrassment of a great **North-country** medium when in the author's presence loud raps, sounding like the snapping of fingers, broke out round his head in the coffee-room of a Doncaster hotel.

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap11)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XI.THE RESEARCHES OF SIR WILLIAM CROOKES (1870-1874)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's colloquially referring to [Northern England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_England). The medium in question is from that region